# Prove equivalence between two Bessel functions relations

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

Given the following equation

$$\frac{J_{n - 1} (u)}{uJ_n (u)} - \frac{K_{n-1}(w)}{wK_n(w)} = 0$$

(where $J$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html), $K$ is the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html), $u, w \in \mathbb{R}$, $u \neq w$ in general)

it should be proved that it is equivalent to

$$\frac{J_{n - 1} (u)}{uJ_{n - 2} (u)} + \frac{K_{n-1}(w)}{wK_{n-2}(w)} = 0$$

by using some recurrence relations (as the ones presented in [this document](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselK/introductions/Bessels/05/)).

By comparing the two (allegedly equivalent) equations, it should be

$$\frac{J_{n - 1} (u)}{J_{n} (u)} = \frac{J_{n - 1} (u)}{J_{n - 2} (u)}$$

$$\frac{K_{n - 1} (w)}{K_{n} (w)} = - \frac{K_{n - 1} (w)}{K_{n - 2} (w)}$$

If it is right, how to proceed now?

The equality should be proved for any integer $n \geq 0$ and at least for any non-negative real values $u,v$. It is used to describe the optical fibers propagation (in documents like [this](http://www.ece.umd.edu/~davis/chapter17.pdf), to obtain (17.104) from (17.103)).

Comment: The last two formulas cannot be valid for general $n,u,w$ because they would imply 
$J_{n-2}(u)=J_n(u)\;$ and $K_{n-2}(w)=-K_n(w),\,$ which is obviously wrong. Please make clear what is intended: Do you seek for special values $n,u,w$ or shall the formulas be valid for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ etc?

Comment: @gammatester I just edited the question to (hopefully) make it more clear.

Comment: A [related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1638830) question.

Comment: @Lucian Thank you. I think it is not directly useful here, but it is certainly a similar problem.